# I want to write a code for a buy condition: closing price has been rising for the last 5 bars

Tags: pine-script

Let's say my strategy is to buy a stock that has been rising for the past 5 bars.

I would write something like this:

`longCondition = (close > close[1]) and (close[1] > close[2]) and (close[2] > close[3]) and (close[3] > close[4]) and (close[4] > close[5])`

However, I have a feeling that there's a simpler way to code this by using a variable that updates itself. I'm not so sure though. How could I improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in functions `rising()` and `falling()`
eg

```
longCondition = rising(close, 5)
```

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_rising

Comment: Thank you so much! There are still so many built-in functions that I haven't come across and are so useful.